# set line color between two points on line

Tags: javascript, three.js

I draw a line in three.js based on an array of vertices, and want to set the color of line to a specific value between two points along the line, which are not vertices. 
These two points are points in a specific distance from the origin of the line, e.g. I want to change the color between a distance of 50 to 100 units along a line of 500 units. How could I accomplish this?

Using `vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors`, I can only specifiy the color between line vertices. I think I need to pass the two points as additional vertices, but how can I get the position with XYZ coordinates along the line?

Thanks for any hints how to accomplish this!

Comment: A custom shader will help. Use `.onBeforeCompile()`, for example, to achieve this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to modify `THREE.LineDashedMaterial()`, using `.onBeforeCompile()`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 250, 500);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(500, 10));

var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(
  [
    new THREE.Vector3(-250, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(250, 0, 0)
  ]
);

var mat = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({
  color: "red"
});
var uniforms = {
  segmentStart: {
    value: 50
  },
  segmentEnd: {
    value: 100
  },
  segmentColor: {
    value: new THREE.Color("yellow")
  }
}
mat.onBeforeCompile = shader => {
  shader.uniforms.segmentStart = uniforms.segmentStart;
  shader.uniforms.segmentEnd = uniforms.segmentEnd;
  shader.uniforms.segmentColor = uniforms.segmentColor;
  shader.fragmentShader = `
    uniform float segmentStart;
    uniform float segmentEnd;
    uniform vec3 segmentColor;
  ` + shader.fragmentShader; // add uniforms
  shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
    `if ( mod( vLineDistance, totalSize ) > dashSize ) {
  discard;
 }`, // remove the part for dash
    ``
  );
  shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
    `gl_FragColor = vec4( outgoingLight, diffuseColor.a );`,
    `gl_FragColor = vec4( outgoingLight, diffuseColor.a );
    if (vLineDistance >= segmentStart && vLineDistance <= segmentEnd) gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(1, 1, 0);
    `
  ); // add showing of a segment


  console.log(shader.fragmentShader);

}

var line = new THREE.Line(geom, mat);
line.computeLineDistances();
scene.add(line);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {

  uniforms.segmentEnd.value = 250 + Math.sin(clock.getElapsedTime()) * 150;
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```